# Systemd default target issue

Tags: systemd

I issued the wrong systemctl.unit directive and now I cannot get to a shell.

I am on fedora 23, I changed runlevel by issuing

```
systemctl set-default rescue.target
```

Now the rescue mode gets stuck and never brings up the shell.

I have tried adding to the kernel

```
systemd.unit=graphical.target
```

But I keep getting kicked to rescue mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pass the following line to kernel param:

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

With `rescue.target` the `bash` should normally already be brought up.

Maybe there is something not working even before `rescue.target` and prevent `systemd` reaches `bash`.

Try:

```
systemd.unit=emergency.target
```

or even pass:

```
init=/bin/sh
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what target is put in the params. I always get the rescue welcome screen. I have a tried multi-user graphical, runlevel2, emergency, but there is no notable difference

Comment: Are you using the right command `systemd.unit`? I mean, you typed `systectl.unit`, is it just a typo you made here?

Comment: Yes a typo. If there is a typo the kernel loading throes an error.

Comment: Right now. No difference

Comment: Seems the kernel command line is not properly loaded? Can you check the kernel log message. Sorry I have no concrete idea now.

Comment: I can't get to a shell. This does it I am fedup of Fedora's weirdness. I am installing Arch on a spare drive and will try to recover my LVM partitions

Comment: I can mount the lvm2 partitions in a Arch live usb without any issue. I will accept your answer: what you suggest is right, the problem lies in Fedora.